# Using redux observable with axios

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-observable

Good Day,

im trying to update my database through the epic and subsequently dispatching the response back to update the store. 
However, while the action eventually dispatches to my store, the payload is undefined. I understand it is some problem with updateArticle not fetching fast enough. How do i allow it to wait for updateArticle to return the response before dispatching to the store?

My epic:

```
  action$.pipe(
flowing left-to-right, calling each function with the output of the last one.
    filter(action => action.type === "ADD_ARTICLE_EPIC"), 
    switchMap(
      action =>
        from(updateArticle(action.payload)).pipe(
          map(action => {
            console.log(action);
            return { type: "ADD_ARTICLE", payload: action.payload };
          })
        )
      // return { type: "ADD_ARTICLE", payload: action.payload };
    )
  );
```

My axios:

```
export const updateArticle = async article => {
  const response = await axios.post(`/articles/updateArticle`, article);
  return response.data;
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To begin with you can use from with promises, so I don't think there is a need to use await in updateArticle. And also, in the map, you are accessing payload from action, but action in the scope of that function is already the response from the request. Try this:

```
action$.pipe(
  filter(action => action.type === "ADD_ARTICLE_EPIC"), 
  switchMap(
    action =>
      from(updateArticle(action.payload)).pipe(
        map(response => {
          console.log(response);
          return { type: "ADD_ARTICLE", payload: response.data };
        })
      )
  )
);
```

and then in your service:

```
export const updateArticle = article => {
  return axios.post(`/articles/updateArticle`, article);
};
```

Comment: Ahh beautiful. Thank you so much. It worked flawlessly!